# iOS build system like RubyMotion without the Ruby? Alternately, will RubyMotion work for games?

Tags: iphone, ios, rubymotion

I'm an avid Emacs user and want to start developing on iOS. I used to write Objective-C back in the days when I used to futz around with GNUStep, but in general, am not productive in it or XCode.

RubyMotion has looked the most promising, but mostly due to the text-mode build system and the non-necessity of XCode rather than the Ruby.

I don't really want to use an overly baroque framework like Unity or its compatriots, and I'd like to be able to release to the app store so the toolchain that jailbreakers use won't work.

Is there a build toolchain for iOS similar to RubyMotion? If not, or if your answer will be to write my own scripts calling xcodebuild (which hasn't worked in the past for me), will RubyMotion work for games?

Answer (score 3):

RubyMotion is Great, and since it compiles down to native, it's fast, too.  I'm working on my second app store release.  I might be mistaken, but it sounds like you think RubyMotion can't release to the app store.  Here's some posts on how:

> http://www.iconoclastlabs.com/cms/blog/posts/submitting-rubymotion-apps-to-the-app-store
>
> http://www.iconoclastlabs.com/cms/blog/posts/updating-a-rubymotion-app-store-submission

As far as frameworks go, you can mix in with any cocopod you want. So you're not limited, and there are already examples out there of basic games written in RubyMotion.

> http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/articles/cocoapods/
>
> http://maniacdev.com/2012/05/example-ios-cocos2d-with-ruby-rubymotion/

It's a good time to jump on the RubyMotion bandwagon, good luck!

Comment: It keeps getting better -- Check out the newly released Cocos2d and Box2d wrapper for RubyMotion: https://github.com/rubymotion/Joybox